# Gluon Client Plugin Android app size realy big

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I'm using the new Gluon Client Plugin to develop android/ios apps with graalvm & javafx.
It works quit well, but why by comparison to the gluon mobile 5.0.X the installed app is so big?

Thats my pom. Maybe its something wrong with the `<reflectionlist/>`? If I remove all the `relfectionList-entries` the apps crashs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.wulfsystems.vow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Retability</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <mainClassName>com.wulfsystems.vow.Rentability</mainClassName>
        <javafx>11.0.2</javafx>
        <attach.version>4.0.6</attach.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JAVAFX -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Gluon  Attaach-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/eu.hansolo/tilesfx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.32</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gluonhq/charm-glisten -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gluonhq/glisten-afterburner -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>glisten-afterburner</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.21-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <graalvmHome>/usr/lib/jvm/graalvm/graalvm-svm-linux-20.1.0-ea+26</graalvmHome>
                    <target>android
                    </target>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>com.wulfsystems.vow.view.KostenmieterechnerPresenter</list>
                        <!-- -->
                        <list>com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField</list>
                        <!-- -->
                        <list>javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader</list>
                        <list>javafx.fxml.FXML</list>
                        <list>javafx.geometry.Insets</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.Button</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.VBox</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.Label</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.HBox</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.Pane</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.shape.Line</list>

                        <!-- -->
                        <list>java.lang.String</list>

                        <!-- -->
                        <list>eu.hansolo.tilesfx.Tile</list>
                        <list>eu.hansolo.tilesfx.TileBuilder</list>
                        <list>eu.hansolo.tilesfx.chart.ChartData</list>
                        <list>eu.hansolo.tilesfx.skins.DonutChartTileSkin</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>gluon-releases</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

The apk itself is `50MB` but the installed app `220MB`.

Comment: I can't offer an explanation but I can confirm, from my own experiments, that this is the order of magnitude that you currently have to expect.

Comment: @mipa Okay. We will see what Gluonhq will do.